# How to update labels in the same asp.net page by C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

I wrote a page which user can input a name and get some infos from the database. In the .cs file I got the texts from the database and assigned them to the labels and in the debugging mode, the labels did change their texts. BUT I don't know how to update them in the same page. I used some ways to update the page, but it updated the whole page and display nothing in the labels. 
How can I achieve this function?

I google it and found the AJAX is a good way, but it's an emergency i have no time to learn AJAX?

does someone have good idea to help me solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Watch this video on how to use AJAX. Fast forward to 1.50 into the video as you don't need to install AJAX. http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/how-do-i-get-started-with-aspnet-ajax. Watch this video for connecting Database and accessing the data http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSwbmc5-y0w&feature=related

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is a postback. When the page posts back to the server, the page is refreshed.

If you want to set the labels and avoid losing the data with a postback, you can do so through an ajax call in your JavaScript code, you can set hidden fields or you can set the values in the Session object (not the best idea). There are numerous ways around this; you just have to pick one.

Do some reading on ajax (it's not as hard as you think). You can call the server through ajax, which will get the data from the Db and return it to your JavaScript as JSON. You can then use that to fill your labels.

You may want to look into an UpdatePanel as well. They aren't the fastest solution available, but they are very easy to implement.

Comment: Thx for your suggestion! I will go to study some javascript. I saw there is some AJAX extension in the toolsbar of Visual Studio. Can i use them to finish my page?

Comment: @user1684696 Sure you can. JQuery also has easy to use Ajax in it as well if you're already using the library. If this answer helped you, be sure to up vote it and accept it. Welcome to SO and good luck.